# Select a date before another date SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite, date, select

I'm trying to select the items that have a expiration date `>=` that an selected date.
I'm using the format yyyy-mm-dd, and this is my sql statement:

`String sql = "SELECT _id, item, value, finalDate FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE date(finalDate) >= date("+selectedDate+")";`

This query always result a "full select" in my database, as if there were no conditions.

Some useful information:

`selectDate` is a String which have a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
I'm executing the query like this:

```
return db.rawQuery(sql,null);
```

Comment: do you have the option to change the date format?  Say to yyyymmdd?  Then you can store it as an integer and do simple greater-than and less-than comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing some single quotes in your query statement...

Try this:

```
String sql = "SELECT _id, item, value, finalDate FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE date(finalDate) >=date('"+selectedDate+"')";
```

**EDIT**

Oh, and check your var name.  You use `selectedDate` in the query but state later in your post that it is `selectDate`...

Comment: I was missing the quotes, like you said ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great.  If the answer was helpful, please accept it (click the check mark next to the answer).  If you feel it was really helpful you could upvote it too (click the up arrow).  Accepting answer helps let people know that your issue is resolved and also gives credit to the person that helped you out.